# Create a nested list with map and list.dirs

Tags: r, list, purrr

First let's set up the folder structure we need for this question.

```
dir.create("A")
dir.create("B")

setwd("A")
dir.create("C")
dir.create("D")

setwd("..")

setwd("B")
dir.create("E")
dir.create("F")

setwd("..")
```

Now let's run this code:

```
list.dirs(recursive = F) %>% 
  map(~list.dirs(path = ., recursive = F))
```

I am getting the following structure:

```
[[1]]
[1] "./A/C" "./A/D"

[[2]]
[1] "./B/E" "./B/F"
```

However, what I want is this structure:

```
[[1]]
[1] "./A/C" 
[2] "./A/D"

[[2]]
[1] "./B/E" 
[2] "./B/F"
```

How can I achieve that?

By the way, the above code worked on my old computer without a problem, but on the new one I am getting the currently described issue. Was there some sort of an update that now requires different handling?

Comment: Aren't both these structures identical? i.e. `[[1]][2]` is in both cases "./A/D" etc... ??

Comment: @dario `map_depth(2) doesn't work on the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to have lists rather than vectors in your main list ?

```
(start <- 
list(
  c("a","b"),
  c("c","d")
))
str(start)
(goal <- 
    list(
      list("a","b"),
      list("c","d")
    ))

str(goal)

# map the lists contents to lists and achieve the goal
identical(goal,
          map(start,as.list))

 #doesnt error : 
map_depth(goal,2,.f = identity)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Any idea why the old version (without your answer) would work on one computer and not on the other? I literally just drove home from work to check if I am crazy, but no, there it works, but at the new computer at job it does not.